# Ruby on Rails Tutorial: How to edit user information without confirming the password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

I've been working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.  Currently, in order to edit any of the User attributes, the user must confirm their password.  Is there any way to update the user attributes without having to do this?

My form looks like this:

```
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :course1 %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :course1 %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Update" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>"
```

and my update definition in users_controller.rb looks like this:

```
def update

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:success] = "Edit Successful."
        redirect_to @user
    else
        @title = "Edit user"
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Currently, the update_attributes action fails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `User` model, you probably have something along the lines of:

```
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation
```

Add an `if` clause as follows, that way it only checks for the confirmation when the password is actually being changed:

```
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => :password_changed?
```

Comment: In my user model I have:   

        `validates :password, :presence =>true, :confirmation => true, :length => { :within => 6..40 }`

I tried:

        `validates :password, :presence =>true, :confirmation => true, :length => { :within => 6..40 }, if=>:password_changed?`

And got a syntax error.  Any ideas?

Comment: I changed my `User` model to match your code and got an error: "Undefined method password_changed?"  How/where do I define it?

Comment: What other validations do you have? Your validation code actually works perfectly for me. What specific validation error does it give you? (e.g. does it say something like "Password doesn't match confirmation"?)

Comment: Here are my other validations:   
  `validates :name,  :presence => true,
     :length   => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :email, :presence   => true,
    :format     => { :with => email_regex },
    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }`  

If I add:   

`validates_presence_of :password, :if => :password_changed?
    validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => :password_changed?`

I get an error that says "NoMethodError in UsersController#Create, undefined method `password_changed?' for #<User:0x00000100c10718>"

Comment: Also, if I do `validates :password, :presence =>true, :confirmation => true, :length => { :within => 6..40 }, :if=>:password_changed?` instead, I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

To slightly refine Dylan's answer, you need to define that password_changed method which was giving you the error. I used a different name, as I don't care if the password has been changed.

```
 validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length => { :within => 6..40 },
                       :unless => :already_has_password?

  private

    def already_has_password?
      !self.encrypted_password.blank?
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bcrypt to encrypt the password, here is the code that worked for me on Rails 4

```
#--Code for User method
validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, :unless => :already_has_password?   
#
private
    def already_has_password?
      !self.password_digest.blank?
    end
```