# rails update_attributes

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1, update-attributes

My user model has

```
validates :password, :presence => true,
                                :confirmation => true,
                                :length => {:within => 6..40}
```

and my update action on the user's controller is

```
def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
            flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
            redirect_to @user
        else
            @title = "Edit user"
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
```

my edit view is

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => @user.errors%>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %> <br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
</div>
```

The problem is that I'd like to update only specific attributes of the model, and not input the password everytime. If I don't input a password (and a confirmation) I get the validation error)

How do I fix the situation?

Comment: I just saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073720/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-how-to-edit-user-information-without-confirming-the-pass I'll test it and report back

Comment: The solution on the link is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next validation rule

> validates :password, :presence => true, :if => lambda { new_record? ||
>   !password.nil? }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr_protected` to exclude some fields from `update_attributes`. See the [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_protected) . An even better way is to use `attr_accessible` to white list the attributes that can be updated by mass-assignment.

Comment: if I use attr_protected, the user won't be able to input the password in the first place